# Serilog - Preserve current log file name and custom archive names

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, serilog, serilog-sinks-file

Currently using:

- Serilog 2.11.0
- Serilog.Sinks.File 5.0.0
- Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile 3.3.0

With the following logger configuration:

```
        _logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
            .WriteTo.File(
                HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/MyApp/App_Data/logs/app.log"),
                rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                fileSizeLimitBytes: 10000000,
                shared: true)
            .CreateLogger();
```

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to maintain the current log file name to name specified in logger configuration and have custom named archived file names. For example:

- app.log (always current log file)
- app_20220913.log (archived log file that rolled on size on 2022/09/13)
- app_20220912.log (archived log file that rolled on size on 2022/09/12)
- app_20220911.log (archived log file that rolled on size on 2022/09/11)

Compared to current behavior:

- import_001.log (current log file)
- import.log (archived log file that rolled on size)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to use both size and day rolling, did you tried using `rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day` also along with current configuration ? or try using [this](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile) package.

Comment: @CodingMytra I want to use rollOnFileSizeLimit, but was wondering if you can configure the format of the file naming as outlined in post. I am guessing it is not possible and would have to write a custom sink.